# after git reset --hard <id> how do I commit?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed the wrong project so I had to `git reset --hard <id>` to the last good commit. Now my files are how I want them in the repo. When I try to commit I get the message.

`error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ohabash/Bulma-grunt-admin.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
ML-2PG8WN:Bulma-grunt-admin ohabash$`

How do I commit what is currently in my file sytem. OR how do i simply undo the bad commit.

Comment: How is Subversion (`svn`) related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was trying to `git push` where I got an the error `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ohabash/Bulma-grunt-admin.git'`

I should have done `git push -f` which forces pushes to remote.

http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html